# Does "expect" and "expected" make any different sense?

Tags: meaning, verb-forms

Please help me figure out this two expressions:

"What do you expect to know?" and "What are you expected to know?"

Answer (score 3):

> What do you expect to know?

"What knowledge do you, personally, expect that you will have?" This is an unusual question because normally people don't "expect" to know something; they either know it or they don't. There are some legitimate uses of it, though; someone might ask this of a friend who's about to go to a pub quiz, for example, to ask which questions they think they might have the answers to.

> What are you expected to know?

"What knowledge does an external entity (person, group etc.) *who is not you* expect that you will have?" Possible usage includes someone asking another about an impending job interview, if they want to know what knowledge the recruiter/interviewer will be expecting the interviewee to possess.

Comment: Yes, I just found a random verb to be filled in and didn't mind about the whole meaning. I understood your point, but to be more certain maybe I should need you to answer one more question, so if say "I'm expected to come to the meeting", does it means "people expect me to come"?

Comment: That's exactly right. You're saying that at least one person who isn't you expects that you'll be at the meeting.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is simply that *What do you expect to know?* poses a question in the "active" voice (for which the answer might be *I expect to know X*).

By contrast, *What are you expected to know?* is "passive" (a typical answer being *I am expected to know X*).

---

To clarify, in the first ("active") version, the explicitly-stated *grammatical subject* of the verb *expect* is ***you***. You're being asked what *you* expect to know.

In the second ("passive") version, the grammatical subject isn't explicitly stated. You're being asked what ***someone else*** (your teacher, for example) expects you to know.

Comment: I don't normally disagree with your answers FumbleFingers, but in this case I think you're wrong: the first one is asking about the expectations of *the person being asked*, while the second is asking about the expectations of *someone who is not that person*. The difference is greater than passive vs active.

Comment: To illustrate my point, let's take an active sentence "I made a mistake" and convert it to passive: "A mistake was made by me." In both cases, a mistake was made, and I was the one who made it. However, in the example given, I could say "I expected to know the answer to question 5." and "I was expected to know the answers to questions 8 and 9." Both are perfectly valid, but one is not a passive version of the active other.

Comment: @John: I got called away before completing this answer, and your comments make it pretty obvious that the bit I never got around to writing is definitely necessary. I maintain that the active/passive distinction is *central* to the issue. Taking account of ***X** being the **actual** information sought by the questioner* as set out in my first two sentences, the only meaningful difference is whether the subject for the verb *expect* is the person being asked (the "active" version), or some unspecified other people (the "passive" version).

Comment: That's fair enough, actually. Given that, is there anything in my answer you think is incorrect?

Comment: @John: There's nothing wrong with your answer so far as I can see. Of course, OP has made things a little awkward by choosing to go with the verb ***know*** here, which as you correctly point out makes for a rather "unusual" question in the first version (a distracting irrelevancy that wouldn't apply with, say, ***do***). I'm guessing from OP's comment (and possibly, his *upvote*), that the question was posed more in the spirit of [“gimme da codez”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210960/) than *What syntactic distinction applies here, and [how] does it affect the meaning?*